# How to join two objects so that one conforms to the shape the other?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow

I am modeling a bottle of 2 parts that need to be joined, however the bottom of the cylinder neck needs to conform to the shape of the bottle's body section. Is there a command that allows wrap these polygons to the polygons of another object's polygons? See below image and you'll see what I am trying to do. Or any suggestions as to the best method to wrap it accordingly?

[image]

[image: bottle in two parts]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you could get the top to fit to the bottle is with the [Shrinkwrap modifier](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier). Here are the steps.

Start by adding a shrinkwrap modifier to the bottle neck. However, that will crush the entire neck on to the bottle, to get around that problem use a [vertex group](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/vertex_groups/vertex_groups.html#vertex-groups).
[image: modifier settings]

Select the bottom edge loop on the bottle neck and assign a new vertex group to it with a weight of one.
[image: vertex group]

Now use that vertex group in the shrinkwrap modifier (pictured above), and you will get the bottom of the neck to match the bottle.

Comment: I followed the directions on answer #1 but it appears nothing happened even after I applied the shrink wrap modifier. Blend file added to my post. You'll see I made the vertice group and shrink wrap modifier added (but in this version not applied).

Comment: Update: Ok this answer worked ONCE I selected the downward vertice triangle icon / option in the modifier option (on your first picture it's the 4th icon over) "Adjust edit cage to modifier result". Then with a slight adjustment to 5 center front (and back) vertices on next edge loop up from the bottom, using "O" for proportional editing to push those vertices inward a little.

Comment: @Marc good to hear you got it working! thanks for letting me know how you did it.

Comment: Note: this will cause Z-fighting, which would be particularly problematic if the OP wants to use a glass shader.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to manually create a hole in the top of the bottle object and join it with the stem object.  Though a bit more time-consuming this method will (as is usually the case with topology problems) usually give a better result than an automatic/procedural solution, especially if you are going to apply a subsurf modifier.

In this example I am using a very low-poly mesh to make the process visually cleaner and easier to follow here, but the same process can be used for higher-poly meshes just as well.

[image]

First take a square selection of the top faces and inset them with <kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

Delete the inset faces, scale the resulting edge border to a circle with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and flatten it with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>`0`</kbd>.  Then merge the overlapping vertices at the edges with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

[image]

Now (in object mode) join the neck object to the bottle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

Select the two edge loops (as pictured above) and connect them with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*.

[image]

Adding a subsurf modifier will smooth the result desirably.

[image]

Comment: WEOW!!  ! Thank you for this and all the work it took to create this. This gives me a ton of new things to learn in blender!

Comment: @Marc, Glad it was helpful!  You may be interested in [this page](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/) for some neat topo tips.

Comment: Sorry.. I made it to Selecting two edges loops and Cntrl + E but with that I command am given a menu, of which there's no option for Bridging.

Comment: @Marc - My bad, it's under the *Specials* [W] menu.

Comment: That worked ;) Thanks. Q though. When bridging edge loops do they need to have the same amount of edges or vertices?

Comment: @Marc - I think so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a boolean modifier with union option.
[image]

Here is off center example.  The union was applied by pressing the [Apply] button.  Next triangulated to show primitive geometry.  Edit Mode. All vertices selected.

[image]

Comment: Tried this method. Selected the bottle neck added boolean modifier selected the bottle body object applied using Union. However when I selected Triangulate modifier there was no option of "primitive geometry" only "Beauty and clip"

Comment: Your are correct ... no such option, just words of explanation.  Triangulate is a menu choice, not modifier.  You can ignore this concept if your object is not animated, beformed, twisted, animated.  Sometimes people want to see the vertex results of a boolean operation.  Small objects in the background need less inspection.

Comment: "Triangulate is a menu choice" - where do I find that menu? Hotkeys?

Comment: @Marc Ctrl+T with selection