# How to smoothly connect rectangle and cone while leaving arches?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, blender-id

Beginner here*

How do I smoothly connect a cube with a cylinder?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43318/how-to-join-two-objects-so-that-one-conforms-to-the-shape-the-other https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228436/how-can-i-model-a-bottle-with-triangular-base-and-circular-top-nail-polish-bot https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238803/how-can-i-model-a-bottle-with-a-solid-glass-bottom-like-this-one/

Answer (score 1):

Create this shape (subdivide a cube, bevel the edges, move up the top vertices):

[image]

Extrude up the top edge, keep the top edge selected, enable the *LoopTools* addon, right click and *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Add new edge loops to round the neck, or to sharpen some edges:

[image]